# mpld3 does not show a figure in ipython notebook

Tags: python, matplotlib, jupyter-notebook

I'm using [mpld3](https://github.com/jakevdp/mpld3) to visualize interactive plots in ipython notebook

It used to work fine. I installed a new computer, with the latest versions of Ipython and Matplotlib.

But when I run:

```
enable_notebook()
plot([1,2],[1,2])
```

instead of getting a plot I get only:

```
Out[8]: [<matplotlib.lines.Line2D at 0x5cb0850>]
```

what am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is probably related to upgrading the library, and having old versions of the javascript hanging around. We haven't put it up on the mpld3 website yet, but you can see some relevant information in the [FAQ section](https://github.com/jakevdp/mpld3/blob/master/doc/faq.rst#ipython-notebook) of the mpld3 git repository.

Comment: So,  I need to upgrade the mpld3 library?